# connectAsync of Expo InAppPurchases always returns undefined in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, in-app-purchase, expo, app-store-connect

In order to implement inAppPurchase using expo am facing some issues.am referring https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/in-app-purchases.i followed all steps mentioned in the document.I ejected my expo for this.In my App.js i write a code to Connects to the app store.

App.js

```
import * as InAppPurchases from "expo-in-app-purchases";
export default class App extends React.Component {
       componentDidMount = async() => {
          const history = await InAppPurchases.connectAsync();
          console.log("history", history);  //Here it is getting undefined...
       }
............
}
```

am getting this error in ios.am building the solution using xcode and run in real device.
what should i do?

Comment: I'm experiencing the same. Did you find the solution?

Comment: Anyone fixed this? It's been 2 years...